# Creating a color map / heatmap in Matlab / Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, heatmap, color-mapping, colormap

I'm using Octave 3.8.1 which is like Matlab and I'm trying to create a color map / heatmap to look something like this

[image: Map]

I have an array **a1** where the 1st col is x, the 2nd col is y and the 3rd col is intensity.  I know I can plot a 2d plot using plot(x,y) but how do I add / show the intensity (the 3rd col) in the plot.

```
a1=
[225.512    2.64537 0.00201692
225.512 2.64537 0.00201692
226.94  1.59575 0.00225557
226.94  1.59575 0.00225557
227.31  1.70513 0.002282
227.31  1.70513 0.002282
227.729 5.34308 0.00205535
227.729 5.34308 0.00205535
227.975 5.12741 0.001822
227.975 5.12741 0.001822]
```

Full dataset is located here https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmhpbelnjoondho/full.csv

Please note that this is just sample data.

Comment: You could try `pcolor` with `shading interp`. Here is an [octave example](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/pcolor.html)

Comment: Most of the 3D plotting tools in MATLAB/Octave require the intensity (`Z`) to be a matrix corresponding to the grid produced by the `x` and `y` data. There isn't enough intensity data in your example to produce a plot resembling that in your question.

Comment: as @IKavanagh says, your data does not conain enough information to plot a surface, as in the image. Can you show a MVCE?

Comment: @Ander Biguri what is MVCE?

Comment: What does `a1` have repeating rows? Is that your full dataset?

Comment: @Dan I updated question and added link to full data set.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmhpbelnjoondho/full.csv

Comment: @RickT https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a1=
[225.512 2.64537 0.00201692
225.512  2.64537 0.00201692
226.94   1.59575 0.00225557
226.94   1.59575 0.00225557
227.31   1.70513 0.002282
227.31   1.70513 0.002282
227.729  5.34308 0.00205535
227.729  5.34308 0.00205535
227.975  5.12741 0.001822
227.975  5.12741 0.001822]
```

In order to plot your heatmap, you need to intensity data as an image (i.e. a 2D matrix). Then you can just plot it using `imagesc` or `imshow`.

In order to do that you'll need to first get a 2D matrix of x values (`X`), and a corresponding 2d matrix of y values (`Y`) so that you can interpolate a grid of z values (`Z`).

```
x = a1(:,1);
y = a1(:,2)
z = a1(:,3)
n = 256;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x),max(x),n), linspace(min(y),max(y),n));
Z = griddata(x,y,z,X,Y);
%// Remove the NaNs for imshow:
Z(isnan(Z)) = 0;
imshow(Z)
```

you might want to normalize `Z` to range from `0` (or in the case of this data, to make the lowest non-zero value equal to zero) to `1` to improve the constrast:

```
m = min(Z(Z~=0));
M = max(Z(Z~=0));
imshow((Z-m)/(M-m));
```

Comment: use `imagesc` for a result more like what the OP asks.